# Pandas Dataframe with dictionary cells | accumulate by values | inefficient apply method

Tags: python, pandas, performance, coding-efficiency

**Given**:

Sample Pandas Dataframe with dictionaries in each cell:

```
user_token_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
      "usr": ["u1", "u2", "u3", "u4", "u7", "u9", "u5", "u8"],
      "colA":   [
            {'a': 7, 'b': 0,'c': 1, 'd':0.1, 'e': 0.8},
            {'a': 0, 'b': 1,'c': 0.1, 'd':0, 'e': 7},
            {'a': 5, 'b': 2,'c': 0, 'd':0.1, 'e': 0.3},
            np.nan,
            {'a': 1.2, 'b': 2.6,'c': 2.2, 'd':0.3, 'e': 5.3},
            {'a': 1, 'b': 0,'c': 0, 'd':0.5, 'e': 2.1},
            {'a': .1, 'b': 0.7,'c': 3, 'd':1.9, 'e': 0.4},
            np.nan,
          ],
      "colB": [
            {'a': 1, 'b': 2,'c': .8, 'd':0, 'e': 0.6},
            np.nan,
            {'a': 0.6, 'b': 5.2,'c': 0.1, 'd':0, 'e': 2.7},
            {'a': 0, 'b': 2,'c': 3.0, 'd':0.1, 'e': 6.3},
            {'a': 1.2, 'b': 2.6,'c': 2.2, 'd':0.3, 'e': 5.3},
            np.nan,
            {'a': 1, 'b': 0.3,'c': 0, 'd':0.5, 'e': 2.1},
            {'a': 0, 'b': 0.5,'c': 0.6, 'd':0.9, 'e': 0},
          ],
      "colC": [
            np.nan,
            {'a': 1.2, 'b': 12,'c': 1.2, 'd':0.6, 'e': 0},
            {'a': 0.6, 'b': 5.2,'c': 0.1, 'd':0, 'e': 2.7},
            {'a': 0.3, 'b': 2,'c': 3.0, 'd':0.1, 'e': 0.3},
            {'a': 0, 'b': .6,'c': .2, 'd':.3, 'e': 5},
            np.nan,
            {'a': 1, 'b': 0.3,'c': 0, 'd':0.5, 'e': 2.1},
            {'a': 4.3, 'b': 0.5,'c': 0.6, 'd':0.9, 'e': 0},
          ],
    }
)
```

[image]

**Goal**:

I'd like to create a new column `col_result` which contains dictionaries with values as accumulated values from other columns.

**Working but *Inefficient* Solution**:

Right now, I have a working solution for small sample `Dataframe` using `apply` method and `Counter` from `collections` modules:

```
from typing import Dict
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd
import functools
    
def sum_dict_values(df: pd.DataFrame, vb: Dict[str, int]):
  df = df.dropna()
  dict_colA = dict(Counter(df.colA)) if "colA" in df else dict.fromkeys(vb.keys(), 0.0)
  dict_colB = dict(Counter(df.colB)) if "colB" in df else dict.fromkeys(vb.keys(), 0.0)
  dict_colC = dict(Counter(df.colC)) if "colC" in df else dict.fromkeys(vb.keys(), 0.0)
  res = dict(functools.reduce(lambda a, b: a.update(b) or a, [dict_colA, dict_colB, dict_colC], Counter()))
  return res


init_bow = {'a': 0, 'b': 1,'c': 2, 'd':3, 'e': 4} # to deal with columns with NaN cells

%timeit -r 10 -n 10000 user_token_df["col_result"] = user_token_df.apply(lambda row: sum_dict_values(df=row, vb=init_bow), axis=1)
# 2.12 ms ± 145 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

[image]
Is there any better and more efficient approach dealing with bigger size of `dict` (`len()>100K`) and `DataFrame` (`.shape > 20K`) ?

Cheers,

Comment: why store dictionaries in cells? Why don't you make the dictionary a series, essentially having multiple index?

Comment: @QuangHoang This `Dataframe` is an input from somewhere else, so I do not have control for manipulating `dict`!

Comment: Once you store data as objects, you forfeit the vectorization benefit of Pandas. Without specifics on *somewhere else*, I don't think you can make any significant improvement.

Comment: A slight syntax improvement to `sum_dict_values` func would be `lambda x: x.dropna().apply(pd.Series).sum().sort_index().to_dict()`, but again, I doubt it'd be any help.

Comment: @QuangHoang Your approach seems quite clean and compact but as you said no improvement for the time efficiency: `user_token_df["col_result"] = user_token_df[["colA", "colB", "colC"]].apply(lambda x: x.dropna().apply(pd.Series).sum().sort_index().to_dict(), axis=1)`

Answer (score 0):

Try with `json_normalize`:

```
user_token_df["col_result"] = (pd.json_normalize(user_token_df["colA"]).fillna(0)
                               .add(pd.json_normalize(user_token_df["colB"]).fillna(0))
                               .add(pd.json_normalize(user_token_df["colC"]).fillna(0))
                               .to_dict("records")
                               )
```